# ASP Nested Repeater Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have ASP Nested repeater like below :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMenu" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title"><asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server"></asp:Label></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-body no-padding">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nama</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptDetail" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <td><asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblChild" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList></td>
                                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblID" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                                        <td><asp:Label ID="LblName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

And here what code behind :
When page loaded it is call a `Load_menu()` :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Call Load_menu()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Page_Load Exception :<br>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here `Load_menu()` function which binding to a repeater :

```
Private Sub Load_menu()
    Try
        sqlstring = "SELECT DISTINCT a.parent, b.name FROM masterMenu a join masterMenu b " & _
            "ON a.parent = b.menuID JOIN rolesDetail c " & _
            "ON a.menuID = c.menuID " & _
            "WHERE b.[status] = 1 "
        DS = SQLExecuteQuery(sqlstring)
        DT = DS.Tables(0)
        rptMenu.DataSource = DT
        rptMenu.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Load_Menu Exception :<br>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

And here how I bind the first repeater `rptMenu` :

```
Private Sub rptMenu_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptMenu.ItemDataBound
    Try
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim rDS As New DataSet
            Dim rDT As New DataTable

            Dim lblHeader As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblHeader")
            Dim dr As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
            lblHeader.Text = dr.Item("name").ToString

            sqlstring = "SELECT a.menuID, a.name, b.[status] " & _
                        "FROM masterMenu a LEFT JOIN rolesDetail b ON b.menuID=a.menuID " & _
                        "WHERE a.[status] = 1 and a.parent= '" & dr.Item("parent") & "' and b.RoleID = '" & roleID & "' " & _
                        "ORDER BY a.menuID "
            rDS = SQLExecuteQuery(sqlstring)
            rDT = rDS.Tables(0)
            rptDetail.DataSource = rDT
            rptDetail.DataBind()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("<b>Error RptMenu Data bound :</b>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

It will bind the second repeater `rptDetail` here :

```
Private Sub rptDetail_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptMenu.ItemDataBound
    Try
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim lblID As Label = e.Item.FindControl("LblID")
            Dim lblName As Label = e.Item.FindControl("LblName")
            Dim cblChild As CheckBoxList = e.Item.FindControl("cblChild")
            Dim dr As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
            lblID.Text = dr.Item("menuID").ToString
            lblName.Text = dr.Item("name").ToString
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("<b>Error RptDetail Data bound :</b>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have make sure all query is valid and working. And I got the following error :

```
Load_Menu Exception :
System.Exception: Error RptDetail Data bound :System.ArgumentException: menuID is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table. 
    at System.Data.DataRowView.get_Item(String property) 
    at LMS.role_detail.rptDetail_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) in D:\Others\Ekspedisi\LMS\konfigurasi\role-detail.aspx.vb:line 165 
    at LMS.role_detail.rptDetail_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) in D:\Others\Ekspedisi\LMS\konfigurasi\role-detail.aspx.vb:line 178 
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem) 
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) 
    at LMS.role_detail.Load_menu() in D:\Others\Ekspedisi\LMS\konfigurasi\role-detail.aspx.vb:line 120
```

Have struggling with this error and no result. I dont understand with means `neither datacolumn`. I have check the table and `menuID` should be exist in that column.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2014.

Here `masterMenu` table and example :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[masterMenu](
    [menuID] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [order] [int] NULL,
    [level] [int] NULL,
    [parent] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [icon] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cssClass] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [url] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [target] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [lastModified] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__MasterMen__lastm__15502E78]  DEFAULT (NULL),
    [status] [smallint] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__MasterMen__statu__164452B1]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__MasterMen__times__173876EA]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK__MasterMe__3214EC271367E606] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [menuID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'A0000', N'Kategori Berat', 100000000, 1, N'A0000', N'fa fa-balance-scale', NULL, N'/master/category.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-03-05 11:51:47.293' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'B0000', N'Transaksi Kontainer', 200000000, 1, N'B0000', N'fa fa-truck', N'', N'/warehouse/transaksi.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-01-25 15:02:58.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'C0000', N'Report', 300000000, 1, N'C0000', N'fa fa-file-text', N'fa fa-chevron-down', N'#', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-03-08 11:41:12.457' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'C0001', N'Daftar Transaksi Kontainer', 301000000, 2, N'C0000', N'fa fa-circle', N'', N'/reports/listContainerTransaction.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-03-08 11:41:12.457' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'C0002', N'Rencana Muat Kapal', 301000000, 2, N'C0000', N'fa fa-circle', N'', N'/reports/loadingPlan.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-03-08 11:41:12.457' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'E0000', N'Konfigurasi', 500000000, 1, N'E0000', N'fa fa-gears', N'fa fa-chevron-down', N'#', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-01-25 15:02:58.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'E0001', N'Master Company', 501000000, 2, N'E0000', N'fa fa-building', NULL, N'/master/company.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-03-05 11:51:47.293' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'E0003', N'Pendaftaran User', 503000000, 2, N'E0000', N'fa fa-user', NULL, N'/konfigurasi/user.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-01-25 15:02:58.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[masterMenu] ([menuID], [name], [order], [level], [parent], [icon], [cssClass], [url], [target], [lastModified], [status], [timestamp]) VALUES (N'E0004', N'Roles', 504000000, 2, N'E0000', N'fa fa-unlock', NULL, N'/konfigurasi/roles.aspx', N'content', NULL, 1, CAST(N'2010-01-25 15:02:58.000' AS DateTime))
```

Comment: looks like it is pointing to rptMenu, select menuID in first query too (in Load_menu()). I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetControl(Of T As Control)(par As Control, cntrl As String) As T
    Return CType(par.FindControl(cntrl), T)
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function GetRepeater(cont As Control, rptr As String) As Repeater
    Return cont.GetControl(Of Repeater)(rptr)
End Function
```

Now modify your Event Handler

```
Private Sub rptMenu_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptMenu.ItemDataBound
    Try
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim rDS As New DataSet
            Dim rDT As New DataTable

            Dim lblHeader As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblHeader")
            Dim dr As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
            lblHeader.Text = dr.Item("name").ToString

            sqlstring = "SELECT a.menuID, a.name, b.[status] " & _
                        "FROM masterMenu a LEFT JOIN rolesDetail b ON b.menuID=a.menuID " & _
                        "WHERE a.[status] = 1 and a.parent= '" & dr.Item("parent") & "' and b.RoleID = '" & roleID & "' " & _
                        "ORDER BY a.menuID "
            rDS = SQLExecuteQuery(sqlstring)
            rDT = rDS.Tables(0)

            ' Add this to get reference to the Nested Repeater
            Dim rptr As Repeater = e.Item.GetRepeater("rptDetail")
            AddHandler rptr.ItemDataBound, AddressOf rptDetail_ItemDataBound
            rptr.DataSource = rDT
            rptr.DataBind()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("<b>Error RptMenu Data bound :</b>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Also, you will need to manually add an `ItemDataBound` handler, you wont be able to access the nested Repeater.  The Event Handler needs to signatured like a normal Sub